# Unable to install SQL Server 2019 because of the missing ODBC driver

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I am unable to install Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition because of a missing ODBC driver 2017 (screenshot attached)

I already installed various version of the ODBC driver, already ran powershell commands to set SchUseStrongCrypto registry value

Still no success

Any advice?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was NOT to deal with SQL Server 2019. We went ahead and installed SQL Server 2022, which installed just fine without any issues